# Bash scripting issues

Tags: linux, bash, unix, debian

For a time I have been working with Linux and Debian in school learning all the basics with setting permissions etc. We have also been working with bash scripts.
I've been trying to search for sites learning the basics of bash scripting but cant find any good material.

So basically I would appreciate if anyone knows a good website/ blog/ video that explains the basics of bash scripting and can link it here.

It would also be greatly appreciated if anyone would take the time to solve these exercises for me so I have something to keep working from:

- Write a bash script that makes a file in a directory
- Write a bash script that uses a variable to create a file with the same name as the variable
- Write a bash script that adds execution permission to the file given as argument to the script

Thanks //Anden

Comment: If you have a well defined question, ask it.  Please don't ask people to do your homework.  Also please read the FAQ.

Comment: Im simply asking for any help that would get me into bash scripting aswell as if anyone would have the pleasure of solving these three script exercises to get me thinking in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link with some basics:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html

For some more detailed stuff:

Command summary: http://ss64.com/bash/

Reference guide: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

And if you really want to become a bash hacker:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

The exercises are straight forward... you really don't need someone to solve them for you, but here's a hint for the 1st one: Bash scripts take arguments (also called parameters). The first is $0 and that is the **script name itself**. The second is $1, which in this case would probably be the directory where your file should go. The third is - you guessed it - $2 and that will probably be the name of the file you want to create. There are any number of ways to create a file, check out the "touch" command.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information!

Comment: Another tip for you: when you test your stuff, runn it in a separate shell.

Comment: Ooops wasn't quite finished. To test your stuff, run it in a separate shell. The syntax is: _bash script-name [argument-list...]_
If you want to get a bit fancier, try the following:
_bash script-name [argument-list...] > log-file-name 2>&1 &_

This will send the STDOUT to the specified log-file, _2>&1_ will ensure that errors (STDERR) go there, too. The _&_ at the end specifies to run it all in the background (for long running tasks).

If you do something hideously wrong in your script, often the executing shell die. Running in a separate shell will save your log-in session.